# Check Azure AD from On Prem?

Tags: asp.net

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is but here goes.
Is it possible to write an ASP.Net application which can list all the Azure AD groups that a user is a member of?
Thanks
P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using the graph API using memberOf against a user object: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

You'll need to set up an app registration in Azure AD, give it the appropriate permissions and then authenticate against it to use the API.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0